# Static folder with blueprints in flask

Tags: python, flask

I have a static file (SF), I try to reach it as per the documentation. So, having a blueprint registered with the name "application", I would expect to find the static file in:

```
/application/static/SF
```

However, this does not work. But if I create the blueprint with an url_prefix condition:

```
application = Blueprint('application',__name__,template_folder='templates',
                        url_prefix='/test',static_folder='static)
```

I am indeed able to find the static file now in:

```
/test/static/SF
```

Is there any particular reason of this strange behavior? Am I misinterpreting the flask docs?

Comment: Can you share the exact code which does not work ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While blueprints are *often* used to enable splitting an application up into distinct sub-applications that is not their only use - they can also be used to attach functionality to the application that is not related to new URL routes (filters, for example).

Because they can be used for more than *just* routes it looks like the decision was made to not auto-mount them.  Because the blueprint *may* be used as a mix-in, it looks like the decision was made to not auto-mount them under a particular sub-url.